# Document Set created programmatically doesn't work properly

Tags: document-set

I have a document library using a document set content type. I can create a new document set through the UI and it works perfectly.

I'm now trying to create a document set in this library programmatically and it's not working properly. Here is the code (based on [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.create.aspx)):

```
// Set some properties
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add("UploadComplete", false);
properties.Add("FilenameCode", code);

// Create the set
DocumentSet invoiceSet = DocumentSet.Create(
  list.RootFolder, code, InvoiceSetContentTypeId, properties, true);
```

**What's not working:**

- icon for the set looks like a folder instead of the document set icon
- clicking on the document set doesn't show the document set home page, it just behaves like a normal document library
- running CAML queries shows that both internal fields `HTML File Type` and `ProgId` should be `SharePoint.DocumentSet` but instead they are blank
- changing a field value on the document set folder doesn't propogate to its contents (although perhaps this is supposed to work differently)

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted the `Document` content type from the library which resulted in Document Sets only working through the UI.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but this did not solve the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the exact same symptoms? If not, you should ask a new question describing the exact issue you're having. If you are then sorry I'm not sure what else would help.

Comment: hi alex i tried your method it did not work. i then tried the the above method and it worked perfectly. i had the exact same issue as you had

Answer (score 2):

J had the some issue.
To solve the problem You must use content type id from the list, which is child of Your custom content type id.

DocumentSet invoiceSet = DocumentSet.Create(list.RootFolder, code, list.ContentTypes.BestMatch(InvoiceSetContentTypeId), properties, true);

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with some folders I had converted to document sets, and I don't know whether this solution will work for you. But I submitted them to the content organiser and let the content organiser put them back into the original location, all the document set properties were correct, I got the icon back, and the welcome page etc.

Like I said, not sure if this will help you, but it may be an option.